# How do I get the angle requested in the figure?

Tags: geometry

I have this problem:

[image]

I have not managed to solve the exercise, but this is my breakthrough:

[image]

How can I continue to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted one of the angle is $30^{\circ}$. Also note that the longer diagonal bisects the $120^{\circ}$ angle. Hence the angles in the top triangle are $30^{\circ}$ and $60^{\circ}$, so the the angle complement to $x$ is $90^{\circ}$, so we must have that $x = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: Exactly, that was what he had thought. But they never tell me it's diagonal, so how do you claim that?

Comment: @Mattiu A segment connecting two non-adjacent vertices in a polygon is by definition a diagonal, right?

Comment: True, but how do you ensure that it is just in the angle and not very close to it? That is my question, I believe that visual appreciation is not a demonstration of that.

Comment: @Mattiu If you wan't to be rigorous then we can't be sure about the other diagonal too. Indeed we have to make that assumption, as otherwise I don't believe that $x$ can be found.

Comment: Then, the exercise must have said that it is diagonal? To be rigorous?

Comment: It should have said, but as I said in this kind of problems it's usually assumed to be true from the picture.

Comment: Many thanks Stefan4024 :D

Answer (score 2):

An easy, general way to solve these problems is to draw a circle around them. Then by symmetry, each of the 6 arcs has a measure of $360^\circ/6=60^\circ$. The angle intercepts two arcs on one side and on arc on the other, resulting in $\frac{120^\circ+60^\circ}{2}=90^\circ$.

In the circle below arc $DCB$ measures $120^\circ$ and $EF$ measures $60^\circ$, so by an angle-intercepting-arc theorem, the angle is the average of the intercepted arcs: $90^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: Good answer ,thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:   draw the segments to the center of the circle, and recognize a rhombus there formed by two equilateral triangles with a common base.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using the symmetry of the figure.

Answer (score 0):

$$x = 360^\circ - 90^\circ - 120^\circ - 60^\circ = 90^\circ$$

[image]

Comment: Is because is a quadrilateral?

Comment: Yes.${} {} {} {}$

Comment: How do you assume it's diagonal? How do you know if it is exactly at the vertex?

Comment: @Mattiu would be a stupid question if the line didn't touch the vertex...